# Assign values of object on another array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects and an array of primitive values. I want to create a new array of objects that maps the values of the first to the latter.

Here's the array of objects:

```
var eventInstances = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "Item 1"
    }, 
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "Item 2"
    }, 
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "Item 3"
    }, 
    {
      id: 3,
      title: "Item 4"
    }, 
]
```

And the array of primitive values:

```
var dates = [1, 2, 3]
```

I want map the objects of `eventInstances` to a new Array of objects with the values of `dateInstances` as keys, which would correspond with the value of `id` in `eventInstances`.

The result should be:

```
var dateInstances = [
  {
    id: 1,
    instances: [
      {
        title: "Item 1"
      },
      {
        title: "Item 1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    instances: [
      {
        title: "Item 1"
      },
      {
        title: "Item 1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    instances: [
      {
        title: "Item 2"
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Sorry, if this is a newbie question, I've been reading up on sorting methods, but I'm quite at a loss here. Any hint would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please also include any code you've written so far to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Your desired output is not valid JavaScript notation.

Comment: @trincot Thanks for the remark, it should be correct now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't need the second array, as all those `id` can be found in the data.

You could collect the data in a map keyed by `id` and then extract the values:

```js
const eventInstances = [{id: 1,title: "Item 1"},{id: 2,title: "Item 2"},{id: 1,title: "Item 3"},{id: 3,title: "Item 4"}];

const map = new Map(eventInstances.map(({id}) => [id, {id, instances: []}]));
eventInstances.forEach(({id, title}) => map.get(id).instances.push({ title }));
const result = [...map.values()];

console.log(result);
```

This creates a `Map` from the data. The `Map` is populated using its constructor argument, which can accept an array of pairs as input. Such a pair will serve as key/value pair in the Map being constructed. The pairs that are given to the constructor look like this:

```
[id, {id, instances: []}]
```

And so the `Map` will have its keys set to `id`s and its values will be objects in the form `{id, instances: []}`. Duplicate `id` values will not result in extra entries... they will be ignored in the process.

The next step is the `forEach` loop, which puts values inside those `instances` properties.

Finally, the keys of the `Map` have served their purpose, they can now be ejected. We only need the values, which are turned into an array through the spread syntax.

Comment: Thanks for this! It works perfectly and does make the code much more concise. Before I was pushing all dates as timestamp from the JSON source to an array, then stored as Set and converted to Array again. Where exactly does your code create a set of unique values? I see that it works put I don't understand where the magic happens.

Comment: Ah yes, but it looks like your intuition went in the right direction: `Map` is not so different from `Set`, except that apart from getting unique keys (dates), you can also link related data to them in the same effort.

Comment: I added some explanation in my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications, this is really helpful!

Answer (score 4):

This function will give you your expected result.

```
dates.map(id=>{  
  return {id:id,
  instances:eventInstances.filter(item =>{
      return item.id === id;
   })
   .map(foundItem => {
      return {title: foundItem.title}    
   })
}});
```

Might be a simpler way to do it, but here's what's happening.  Use `map` to iterate through your dates array.  Then `filter` to find items in eventInstances that match, then `map` through those again to just return the title.

[Array.map docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

[Array.filter docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Wow, thanks! I seemed to got the entire concept of maps and filters completely wrong. I think I finally get to wrap my head around it now. It works perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for an object where the `key` equals to the `id`, and the `value` equals to an array of titles, like:

```
{
    "0":[
        "title1",
        "title2"
    ],
    "1":[
        "title1",
        "title2"
    ],

}
```

To achieve that you need:

```
var dateInstances = {};


for(let i =0; i<eventInstances.length;i++){

    if (!Array.isArray(dateInstances[eventInstances[i]["id"]])){
        dateInstances[eventInstances[i]["id"]] = [];
    }
    dateInstances[eventInstances[i]["id"]].push(eventInstances[i]["id"]["title"]);

}
```